# HttpClient Post invoking Web API Post method multiple times

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

below Angular code invoking the WebApi POST method multiple times, please help me to resolve this.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient,HttpErrorResponse,HttpHeaders,HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';
import {IUserInfo} from './user-info';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Http,Response,RequestOptions,Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

saveNewPersonDetails(personDetails) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

    return this._http.post(this._webApiUrl + "person",personDetails, {headers: headers})
    .subscribe(personData => this.personData=personData);
}
```

Comment: post  the code from where you are calling this. i.e component class.!

Comment: I guess the `webApiUrl` isn't exactly the same URL+port as where Angular is loaded and therefore you have a CORS situation. The first request is a OPTIONS preflight request (made by the browser and no way to influence from code), and only the 2nd is the actual POST request. You need to ensure to handle the OPTIONS request properly for CORS for this configuration to work (just a guess though because of limited information available)